# MEF and plugins using IOC

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef

I'm currently using WPF and .NET 4.5, my purpose is to build a desktop app that supports plugins using MVVM.

Using MEF, I can import plugins with

`pluginLoader = new PluginLoader<IPlugin>(path);`

**IPlugin** is the interface that expose the method that app itself should use, plus the view object that app dinamically shows on the main window.

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    [...]

    object View { get; }
}
```

Here's my doubts:

How can I use IoC with this architecture? I'm currently using TinyIOC and there's no reason to change it so far.

By the way, since I'm using MVVM, I need both viewmodel and view components.
For this purpose, I thought about exposing IPlugin so made:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    object View { get; }

    object ViewModel { get; } // called after Init()

    void Init(); // called after plugin resolution
}


public class MyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    MyViewModel vm;

    MyView view;

    void Init()
    {
        // use TinyIOC to init service and resolve viewmodel
    }

    object ViewModel 
    { 
        get
        {
            return vm;
        }
    }

    object View
    { 
        get
        {
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

What do you think about this? Can it works?

Comment: Is your plugin a view basically? or is it like a module(containing many views and viewmodels and services, etc')?

Comment: The second one, need one view, viewmodel and services provided by injection dependency

Comment: You need to separate the services and the view/viewmodel.
The Plugin can Init the services but view/viewmodel should come from another place as a set. remember that if anyone would want to override the instance of the view or viewmodel, they will have to override the entire plugin.